# Integral function of a interpolating polynomial in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, integral

I have a set of points, and on those points I have used scipy in order to calculate the interpolating polynomial. I wish to have the primitive of that function

```
self.p=interpolate.interp1d(self.__discreteDistribution['x'], self.__discreteDistribution['y'], kind='cubic')
```

I can easily use scipy to calculate the **value** of the integral over an interval, using

```
integrate.quad(self.p, 0, max)
```

What I want instead is to have the primitive of self.p().
I have found sympy, but I do not have an analytical version of my interpolating polynomial.

What would you do in these occasion?

Comment: Well, the object is going to be based on a [B-spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline). To have access to to the parameters of that spline (knots and coefficients), you're better off using the spline directly, with `interpolate.UnivariateSpline` or `interpolate.splrep` instead of `interp1d`.

Comment: what form of output do you want? A single polynomial, or do you want a spline? Do you need help using the functions I named above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a piecewise interpolator (as opposed to a global polynomial interpolation), there are several ways you can do it with scipy:

Method 1: UnivariateSpline.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(8)

In [3]: y = x

In [4]: from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

In [5]: from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, UnivariateSpline

In [6]: spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=0)

In [7]: spl.<TAB>
spl.antiderivative        spl.get_coeffs            spl.roots
spl.derivative            spl.get_knots             spl.set_smoothing_factor
spl.derivatives           spl.get_residual          
spl.ext                   spl.integral              

In [8]: spl.integral(0, 1)
Out[8]: 0.5000000000000001
```

Two quirks of UnivariateSpline: first, use `s=0` for interpolation (as opposed to least-square fitting). Second, watch out for extrapolation for out-of-bounds. By default, `UnivariateSpline` extrapolates out-of-bounds values (this can be controlled in constructor), but `.integral` assumes the spline is zero out of bounds.

```
In [9]: spl.integral(-1, 1)
Out[9]: 0.5000000000000001
```

Method 2: splev, splrep and splint.

```
In [13]: from scipy.interpolate import splev, splint, splrep

In [14]: tck = splrep(x, y, s=0)

In [15]: splint(0, 1, tck)
Out[15]: 0.5000000000000001
```

This is equivalent to using UnivariateSpline, only the interface is a bit different. See the docs for details.

Method 3: interp1d.

Under the hood, `interp1d` also uses b-splines (unless you request kind='linear' or 'nearest'), but the evaluation routines are different.
`interp1d` constructs a callable, which can then be fed to a general-purpose integrator.

```
In [18]: from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

In [19]: interp = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

In [20]: from scipy.integrate import quad

In [21]: quad(interp, 0, 1)
Out[21]: (0.5000000000000024, 5.5511151231258095e-15)
```

Again, watch out for out-of-bounds values: The behavior of the result constructed by interp1d is not very useful (even though it's controllable to an extent).

Answer (score 1):

That `interp1d method` seems to just give you a function object for the interpolation function which allows you to evaluate arbitrary function values.

Looking at the documentation I see no interface to the internal representation. 
I guess it is a sum of piecewise defined cubic polynomials.
In that case your primitive would be a sum of piecewise definied quadratic polynomials. Would that really be useful to you?

Aside calculating the splines directly (as suggested in the comments by askewchan) you could try to use the function values with `approximate_taylor_polynomial` ([doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.approximate_taylor_polynomial.html)) to resample and get `poly1d` (doc) objects on each subinterval and then use  `poly1d.integ` ([doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html)) on each subinterval to get the coefficients of a primitive.